# Get the added class from body and do somthing

Tags: javascript

I have two button when i click one one of them class "active-1" add to body
and another button, class "active-2" add to body.
When i want to get one of this class, don't work.
I use this code to get class "active-2":

```
if ( $("body.active-1").hasClass("active-2") ) {
    // Do Somtihng
}
```

what is the problem and what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: What does 'When i want to get one of this class, don't work.' mean ?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' class added');
        $('body').removeAttr('class').addClass($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" id="active-1">active-1 add</button>
<button class="button" id="active-2">active-2 add</button>
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for reply, but this doesn't work

Comment: you have to remove `active-1``class while activaitng `active-2` right .?

Comment: no, forget this question, when one class added to body how can i get that class
`if ( $("body").hasClass("class") ) {
    // Do Somtihng
}`

Comment: if you want to get the class you should use like this : `$('body').attr('class')`